# Не могу сделать регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
https://vk.com/vladchocoladofficial?w=wall192868914_512
```

нужно сделать в

```
https://vk.com/wall192868914_512
```

Comment: И, как пытались сделать, что не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
$str = 'https://vk.com/vladchocoladofficial?w=wall192868914_512';
$r = preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/vk\.com\/)[a-z0-9\/]+\?w=([a-z0-9_]+)/','$1$2',$str);
echo $r;
```